# How to succinctly sum up N multiple elements along 3rd dimension of multidimensional array?

Tags: matlab

rlutcs is a 360x180x130 array. I want the summed array to be 360x180x1.

E.g. I want to take the sum of `rlutcs(:,:,1) + rlutcs(:,:,2) + ... + rlutcs(:,:,12)`

or

`rlutcs(:,:,2) + rlutcs(:,:,2) + ... + rlutcs(:,:,13)`

This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169394/how-to-succinctly-sum-up-multiple-elements-along-3rd-dimension-of-multidimension, but this time I just want to take running mean sums of 12 elements along the 3rd dimension of the array (where the 3rd dimension is months).

Comment: Try: `rlutcsSum=sum(rlutcs,3)`

Comment: But what about the 1st-12th elements of the 3rd dimension? Or the 2nd-13th elements of it?

Comment: So then your result would be 360x180x118 wouldn't it? (118 = 130 - 12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `rlutcsSum=sum(rlutcs(:,:,1:12),3)`, as per @Werner's comment.